# What is meant by statistical inevitability?

Tags: meaning, phrases, meaning-in-context, negation, double-negation

What is meant by statistical inevitability? For e.g. in [Editorial: summer accidents no statistical inevitability - Estonian news](https://news.postimees.ee/1241188/editorial-summer-accidents-no-statistical-inevitability)

inevitability means something that can't be avoided

---

EDIT: From your comments, I understood: (AM I CORRECT?)

So does statistical inevitability mean that the event can't be avoided due to randomness (as multiple factors are involved)?

So the title "summer accidents no statistical inevitability" has double negation and it means that Summer Accidents can be avoided even though it has several multiple causal factors. Am I correct?

Comment: Further than “the quality of being inevitable from a statistical standpoint” what are you really asking?

Comment: The statistics say that there will be X accidents, and the article is saying it is down to the individual – is no inevitability – not inevitable.

Comment: "Inevitability" is the *quality* of not being avoidable. Something that can't be avoided is an *inevitable* (a word that is both adjective and noun).

Comment: It simply means that according to collected statistics there little  chance to avoid what is being considered as a possibility.

Comment: That it is inevitable that editors will invoke statistics in myriad troubling ways.

Comment: @Jim Please see my edit. Have I understood it correctly?

Comment: @LPH Please see my edit. Have I understood it correctly?

Comment: @WeatherVane Please see my edit. Have I understood it correctly?

Comment: I think so. To me, the article is saying that Estonians should not just shrug and say "the statistics tell us that a certain number of accidents are inevitable" but activley try to do something about it.

Comment: https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/inevitability   // https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/inevitability: The inevitability of something is the fact that it is certain to happen and cannot be prevented or avoided.  // https://www.lexico.com/definition/inevitability: The quality of being certain to happen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A "statistical inevitability" is something that is guaranteed (or at least extremely likely) to happen based on historical statistics.

In the article you linked to, statistics show that deaths in traffic or due to drowning increase significantly during hot weather. Estonian politicians claim that they can't eliminate these additional deaths completely, the best they can hope for is to reduce them to the amount in the rest of Europe.

The article title is claiming that these deaths are not inevitable, we should not assume that statistics are unavoidable predictions of the future. We can learn from the past and try to mitigate the causes of these extra deaths.